# remove fast moving propeller blades from video

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing

I'd like to remove propeller blades from a captured video or at least make them less visible by somehow averaging with subsequent frames. It seem to me that this should be possible as in subsequent frames the propeller blades are at very different rotation angles.

I don't need this in real time but for video post processing only. It's ok if it's slow.
I've already a chain of several other ffmpeg processing options so if there's a solution with ffmpeg (on linux) that would be ideal.

Here's an [example video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rToIC.jpg).

Here's an example image:

[image: example image of propeller blades]

Answer (score 1):

You can drop the framerate and blend the frames it dropped with the ones that remain.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -vf minterpolate=fps=30 output.mov
```

If your video is 60fps, reducing it to 30 fps, you will basically have 2 original frames covering the same new frame. By blending them, it averages the frame with the blade with one that doesn't have the blade, blurring the propeller blades significantly.
The more frames you drop, the more it blends with the background.
Obviously, you need to have a high framerate in your source material.

Comment: Martijn - thanks.

I tried that, see https://imgur.com/7VMBtgL by reducing the frame rate from 30 to 15 (minterpolate=15). Unfortunately the original frame rate is 30 fps only. The props slightly improved but also are distorted somehow.
I could get the props even better reduced by tblend=all_mode=lighten, see https://imgur.com/NwSurur.

Answer (score 1):

What about ffmpeg's *[tblend](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#tblend)* filter:

```
ffmpeg -i 98Ymysd.mp4 -vf decimate=cycle=2,tblend=all_mode=lighten
corrected.mp4
```

I added *decimate*, because the video you linked had 60 fps but repeated every frame.  Probably you can skip that operating on your original 30 Hz videos.

tblend leaves some chroma artifacts, but the propeller blades are gone...

Unfortunately, since tblend=all_mode applieds to all pixels, it overall degrades the image quality.  Maybe one could develop a smart formula to only correct a pixel if it is much darker than the other one.

To really do it properly, one would estimate the 3d motion of the camera relative to the mountains and then apply some low pass filtering (over more than only 2 frames as tblend) of the corresponding pixels, only adjusting the color whan the blades are in the foreground, taking the colors from neighboring frames, motion adjusted.  That is beyond ffmpeg.